# docker volume - who overrides who - file within docker or existing file outside?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

let's say I have file solr.xml inside docker and the parent folder is mapped to host folder outside.

Now the solr.xml was updated and I remove the container and reinstall a new image and start a new container - I see that the already existing "old" file isn't overridden.

Isn't that like an expected behavior? what would be the best practice? I don't want to start handling the "remove" volumes, cause there are files created by customer over there...

BTW - the mapping is done via docker volume container

Comment: I'm confused about your question. If you have a volume mounted to a host directory, the files on the host and in the container are the same. Are you asking, what happens to the host file, if someone changes the file in the container? If so, it would change as well since it is the same file.

Comment: thanks. what if the container itself is being removed and starting a whole new container (from the same image) - that has newer file within? I must say that files stay at the host folder even after removing the docker volume.

Comment: If you are mounting a volume from a host directory, the files come from the host directory instead of from the image. If you are not mounting from a host directory, then they will come from the image.

Comment: Since you are using a data volume container that is a little different. Can you update your question with your setup for your containers? And the run command you use to mount the volumes?